# RHEL boot partition size during auto-installation

Tags: redhat, partition, boot

We are installing some servers with same RHEL image.

During the installation, all but one, have had no problems with a 250MB boot partition.

The one server, after the installation has received boot partition in size of 65M.
All the installation is automatic from the network and based on the install server which serves as DHCP & TFTP server.
(This small 65M partition causes the full installation to fall as there is some kernel patch which should be installed).

Where / how to identify where is the problem?

**Edit:**

I've found following:

```
# Disk Partioning
clearpart --all --initlabel 
part /boot --size 64 --asprimary --ondrive=sda 
part pv.1 --size 286000 --ondrive=sda volgroup vg00 --pesize=65536 pv.1
```

Comment: Could you please add the relevant portions of your kickstart configuration, if any?

Comment: I've found following: # The following is the partition information you requested
# Disk Partioning 
clearpart --all --initlabel

part /boot --size 64 --asprimary --ondrive=sda

part pv.1 --size 286000 --ondrive=sda


volgroup vg00 --pesize=65536 pv.1

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your kickstart:

```
# The following is the partition information you requested 
# Disk Partioning 
clearpart --all --initlabel 
part /boot --size 64 --asprimary --ondrive=sda 
part pv.1 --size 286000 --ondrive=sda volgroup vg00 --pesize=65536 pv.1
```

The "part /boot --size 64" means exactly that. 64Mb /boot partition. Your problem lies with the automatic provisioning system. The kickstart should be modified to reflect more appropriate partition sizing.

Comment: And I recommend 500 MB for future growth, as this is the recommended size for RHEL 7.